# How to delete a property from prototype in an array of objects from MongoDB?

Tags: javascript, mongodb

I have a database in MongoDB/Mongoose and I have a collection of users which I use both for authentication and as a list of contacts to display in the frontend.

I don´t want to send the user's passwords over to the user when I want to display the list of contacts, so want to delete it from the collection before sending the list back.

So I have something like this

```
readAll(req, res, next) {
  User.find()
    .then(users => {
      users.forEach(user => {
        delete user.password;
      });
      res.send(users);
    })
    .catch(next)
},
```

This is now working; even though `delete user.password` returns true, it does not delete anything.
As User is a class that I defined as a ModelSchema in Mongoose, password is part of the prototype, so it can´t be removed like that.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/delete

I tried doing something like this
`delete User.prototype.password;`
but it does nothing.

How can I do this?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At query level, you can use [projection](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.find) to select/deselect the fields you want i.e.

```
readAll(req, res, next) {
  User.find({}, '-password')
    .then(users => {
      res.send(users);
    })
    .catch(next)
},
```

or using the Query **[`select()`](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#query_Query-select)** method

```
readAll(req, res, next) {
  User.find().select('-password')
    .then(users => {
      res.send(users);
    })
    .catch(next)
},
```

---

Another approach would be to change the select attribute of the field at the schema definition level, e.g.:

```
email: { type: String },
password: { 
    type: String, 
    select: false 
},
...
```

and query as normal:

```
readAll(req, res, next) {
  User.find()
    .then(users => {
      res.send(users);
    })
    .catch(next)
},
```

Comment: I didn´t know about `select: false`, it totally makes sense, thanks!